# Show or Show Dialog block other forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms. First is a simple notepad, and i make a find function. Is works very good, but i add `this.Close();` to get the resultate. If i don't close the FindForm, the action of Find button not work. I see the first form is blocked and i can't write another text. if i delete `this.close()` and i close FindForm after i press Find is work. 
How i can open the FindForm in a new thread? i use `FindForm f = new FindForm();` and `f.showDialog();`
If i make a `Thread Th`; and i use this thread to open the FindForm, my function will not work anymore. Is any method to open other form without block first form?

FindForm

```
public FindDialog()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void button_Find_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.FindText = textBox_Text.Text;
    this.Close();
}
```

MainForm

```
public void findNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    FindDialog gtl = new FindDialog();
    gtl.Show();
    richTextBox1.Select();

    if (FindText != null)
    {
        k = richTextBox1.Find(FindText);
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the actual code.  You can't use background threads for gui objects.

Comment: Do you want to open single form and also make the parent form functional?

Comment: private void button_Find_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.FindText = textBox_Text.Text;
            this.Close();
        }

Comment: and for Form1:           public void findNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FindDialog gtl = new FindDialog();
            gtl.ShowDialog();
            richTextBox1.Select();

            if (FindText != null)
            {
                k = richTextBox1.Find(FindText);
            }
             
        }

Comment: Put the code in your post.  There is an edit link for that.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. i forgot

Comment: A RichTextBox is _not_ Notepad, but rather the other way around; Notepad is a simple application build around a RichTextBox. You had me confused into thinking that you were reading another program's memory...

Comment: is a simple notepad with save, open, replace, find and go to line. but i can't make a good find function. i try to learn C# with simple programs.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `ShowDialog` will block the caller until the dialog is closed (i.e. it is modal) - if you don't want this behaviour then call `Show` which will open the child form modelessly (i.e. the calling code can continue)

For example, you could do something like:

```
public void findNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    FindDialog gtl = new FindDialog(); 
    gtl.Show(); // Execution will continue immediately
    richTextBox1.Select(); 
    if (FindText != null) 
    { 
        k = richTextBox1.Find(FindText); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If i use Show is not work... i mean.. is working, but i need to close and open again to find first variable

Comment: so, first time don't find anything

Comment: To have the parent react to actions the child window, you *probably* want to raise an event, or pass a `delegate` to call, rather than rely on setting properties, or at the very least do your search when the property is set.

Comment: and how i can modify the setting. i want to use Show(), but to work like ShowDialog(). i am beginner and i don't understand why ShowDialog work very well from first search, and Show() return first time 0. Example. First time if i use Show(), i search for a. If i press Find he return me nothing. If i open again and i search for b, he return me a.

Comment: @ Anrei Rowland already gave you the solution: you need an event. Right now you have a race condition because you are calling `richTextBox1.Find()` before `FindText` is set; `ShowDialog()` worked because that was a blocking call that halted execution in your click event handler until the dialog was closed.